# Orbeon 3.9.1PE upgrade to 4.1CE

Tags: orbeon

Tomcat 7

Orbeon 4.1CE

After using 4.1CE, it cannot read the handwritten form in "orbeon/conf/resources/forms/"

Is there any new file need to define in 4.1 version?

---

Now, I know that the properties-local.xml affects this problem.
Is there any sample of properties-local.xml for 4.1CE?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you're upgrading, I'd recommend you upgrade to the latest version ([4.9 at the time of this writing](http://www.orbeon.com/download)), since [4.1 is already quite old](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Orbeon-Forms-release-history).

Now, regarding your specific question, I can't remember Orbeon Forms ever using a `orbeon/conf/resources/forms` folder. Maybe `orbeon/conf/resources` was setup as a resource folder in your `web.xml`? If not, this must have been a directory your app was explicitly reading from.

About the `properties-local.xml`, you can define your own values for properties to configure the way Orbeon Forms works, and for more on this I'd recommend you go through the [documentation about properties](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Installation-~-Configuration-Properties).